# Excel VBA code edit to show two or more values in separate columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the code below that works perfectly but I would like it to show two or more green(RGB(0,176,80)) cell values in separate cells in different columns  within the same row instead of being shown together in the same cell with a + sign?

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim row As ListRow
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim formula As String

    For Each row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable").ListRows
        formula = ""
        For icol = 1 To row.Range.Count - 1
            With row.Range(1, icol)
                If .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then formula = formula & .value & "+" '.Address(False, False)
            End With
        Next icol
        If formula <> "" Then row.Range(1, icol).value = Left(formula, Len(formula) - 1)
    Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim row As ListRow
    Dim nCols As Long, icol As Long
    Dim formula As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable") '<--| reference your table
        nCols = .ListColumns.Count - 1 '<-- "fix" its initial columns number since subsequent operations will increase it
        For Each row In .ListRows
            formula = ""
            For icol = 1 To nCols
                With row.Range(1, icol)
                    If .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then formula = formula & .Value & "+" '.Address(False, False)
                End With
            Next icol
            If formula <> "" Then
                arr = Split(Left(formula, Len(formula) - 1), "+") '<--| fill an array with 'formula' string elements separated by "+"
                row.Range(1, icol).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr '<--| write array content into current row last column adjacent cells
            End If
        Next row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant as always. Worked perfectly. comments well advised too.